# Cells property causes run time error '1004'

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I keep getting the *application defined or object defined* error and the codes in ** gets highlighted. How can I fix this?

```
 Private Sub Update_Click()
  answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to update the Staff Record?", 
  vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Update Staff Record")
  If answer = vbYes Then
    *Cells(Row, 1) = TextBox6.Text*
    Cells(Row, 2) = TextBox1.Text
    Cells(Row, 3) = TextBox2.Text
    Cells(Row, 4) = TextBox3.Text
    Cells(Row, 5) = ComboBox1.Text
    Cells(Row, 6) = ComboBox2.Text
    Cells(Row, 7) = TextBox4.Text
    Cells(Row, 8) = ComboBox3.Text
    Cells(Row, 9) = TextBox5.Text
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You miss the context here,  `Cells` can't be used alone. 
Try something like `ActiveSheet.Cells(...`. Also, what's the value of `Row`?

Comment: In recent past many such questions have been asked and I think this one is possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1127224. ☺

Comment: @RajeshS to propose a duplicate the target question needs to have at least one answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because you haven't defined a value for the `Row` variable. Do that like this:

```
Row = value
```

Where `value` is an integer specifying the worksheet row you want all of your Cells statements to operate on.

For example, if your code should affect row 2, your code would look like this:

```
Private Sub Update_Click()
  Row = 2
  answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to update the Staff Record?", 
  vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Update Staff Record")
  If answer = vbYes Then
    Cells(Row, 1) = TextBox6.Text
    Cells(Row, 2) = TextBox1.Text
    Cells(Row, 3) = TextBox2.Text
    Cells(Row, 4) = TextBox3.Text
    Cells(Row, 5) = ComboBox1.Text
    Cells(Row, 6) = ComboBox2.Text
    Cells(Row, 7) = TextBox4.Text
    Cells(Row, 8) = ComboBox3.Text
    Cells(Row, 9) = TextBox5.Text
 End If
End Sub
```

---

Also, here's a more concise way to use the MsgBox function to execute code based on the user's response:

```
If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to update the Staff Record?", _
  vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Update Staff Record") = vbYes Then
    *run this if user clicks Yes*
End If
```

This approach doesn't store the user's response in a variable then test it separately. Instead it does the same thing in one line of code. (However if you need to use the user's response again later in your code then storing it in a variable would be the better choice.)